# calling template methods when the type is not know

Tags: c++, templates

I have `template method` but i do not know the type. I have somehow managed to get the type of the object and now I have end up with big `if-else` loop like

```
if ( type == "char") {
    templateMethod<char>();
} else if ( type == "int" ) {
    templateMethod<int>();
}
.....
```

Is there any `template trick` to avoid such big `if loop`. My code is getting very ugly now.

Comment: I have a feeling that templates are meant to solve exactly this problem, but at compile time. Can you give some more information on what are you trying to achieve? type of *what* is not known?

Comment: The type of *what*? It's a bit difficult to tell anything without knowing this bit of information. Depending on the answer, the recommended approach could be "use virtual functions", or perhaps something else.

Answer (score 2):

You should practically never need to explicitly determine the type of an object in C++. That's exactly what templates are meant to help you with.

You provided only a small bit of code, but I think what would solve your problem easiest is to have templateMethod take the object whose type you are currently determining as a parameter, even if it isn't going to use the object.

So instead of:

```
template <typename T> void templateMethod() {
  // ...
}

// later
if ( type_of_x == "char") {
  templateMethod<char>();
} else if ( type_of_x == "int" ) {
  templateMethod<int>();
}
```

Do this:

```
template <typename T> void templateMethod(T x) {
  // ...
}

// later
templateMethod(x);
```

This will cause the compiler to automatically call `templateMethod` with the template type `T` being equal to the type of `x`, the variable that in your current code you are attempting to determine the type of.

Answer (score 0):

Template Specialization:

```
template <typename T> void templateMethod() {}

template <> void templateMethod<char>() {

}

template <> void templateMethod<int>() {

}
```